# How to add select all in django?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

i want have a form like this https://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=63.0_9

How i can make this form in django ?

Thank you

this is my form i use django-selectable:

```
from django import forms

from rapidsms.router import send

from selectable.forms import AutoCompleteSelectMultipleField

from .lookups import ConnectionLookup



class MessageForm(forms.Form):
  message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
  connections = AutoCompleteSelectMultipleField(
     lookup_class=ConnectionLookup)


  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['connections'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Add a Recipient'
    self.fields['message'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Message'

  def send(self):
    message = self.cleaned_data['message']
    connections = self.cleaned_data['connections']
    return send(message, connections)
```

Comment: where are your forms?

Comment: Sorry, i use django selectable for my form but no feature for select all.

Comment: oh, sorry lol...